# Kotlin: 'val' on secondary constructor parameter is not allowed

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I have following class:

```
class Person(val name: String) {
    private var surname: String = "Unknown"

    constructor(name: String, surname: String) : this(name) {
        this.surname = surname
    }
}
```

But when I want to have the **name** parameter immutable in second constructor:

```
constructor(val name: String, surname: String) : this(name) {
    this.surname = surname
}
```

I have the following compile-time error:

> Kotlin: 'val' on secondary constructor parameter is not allowed

Can someone explain why is Kotlin compiler not allowing to do this?

Comment: `name` is immutable reference because it's declared as `val` in primary constructor.

Comment: all parameters in kotlin functions and constructors are immutable, i.e. `fun foo(name : String)` translates to java `public void foo(@NotNull final String name)`

Comment: @msrd0 **primary constructor** can use val/var

Comment: @BertKing Yeah what a surprise ...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Parameters in Kotlin are always immutable. Marking a constructor parameter as a `val` turns it into a property of a class, and this can only be done in the primary constructor, because the set of properties of a class cannot vary depending on the constructor used to create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the great answer of [yole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112593/8073652), the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) is pretty clear as well:

> Note that **parameters of the primary constructor** can be used in the initializer blocks. They can also be used in property initializers declared in the class body.
>   [...] In fact, for declaring properties and initializing them from the **primary constructor**, Kotlin has a concise syntax:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) {
    // ...
}
```

> Much the same way as regular properties, the properties declared in the **primary constructor** can be mutable (var) or read-only (val).

This all does not apply to secondary constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer is correct in explaining why your initial attempt did not work. As such, given your particular scenario, I would inverse the solution and make your secondary constructor the primary, and make that second parameter have a default value.

```kotlin
data class Person(val name: String, val surname: String = "Unknown")
```

Also, if the class's purpose is to simply hold data, I would make it a `data class` to improve its handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the variable as val or var in the class you inherit from

```
   open class Human(val name: String) constructor(name: String) {
            open fun showInfo()
        {
            println("Show Info")
        }
        }

class Person:Human {

constructor(name: String) : super(name)
    private var surname: String = "Unknown"
  override fun showInfo() {
        println("$name And surname is $surname")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: While your solution would work, it would needlessly increase complexity. It would be better to just simplify the original class and use a single primary constructor with an optional parameter for the surname.